# AspectJ LTW + Spring Boot + Inbuilt Tomcat Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I m trying to add aspectJ LTW integration in our Springboot Application.  I m trying to use java way of specifying  TomcatInstrumenatbleClassLoader and TomcatLoadTimeWeaver instead of xml way.

[Refereing Spring Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction-defn:%7E:text=the%20default%20value.-,Environment%2Dspecific%20configuration,-This%20last%20section)
But when starting my app it errors out like below

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/spring.factories]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/spring.factories]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getBootstrapRegistryInitializersFromSpringFactories(SpringApplication.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:285)
    at com.org.pack.app.Application.main(Application.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/spring.factories]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getBootstrapRegistryInitializersFromSpringFactories(SpringApplication.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:285)
    at com.org.pack.app.ImportApplication.main(ImportApplication.java:37)
```

My code goes as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({<Our Depedencies>})
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
    /**
     * Main method
     * 
     * @param args - arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultResourceLoader defaultResourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader(new TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader());
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(defaultResourceLoader, Application.class);
        application.run(args);
        // SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    /**
     * Load Time viewer for tomcat based app
     * 
     * @return - Instance of Intrumentaiton Load TIme Weaver
     */
    @Bean
    public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
        return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    }
}
```

Dependencies (excluding other dependencies): Multi-module project
Parent Pom

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Project Root POM

```xml
          <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
               <version>9.0.74</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.18</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.20</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.20</version>
            </dependency>
```

Module's POM

```xml
<!-- spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The document also says for tomcat 6.0 or higher the setting is not needed, but getting error like

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '<our entity factory class>' defined in class path resource [com/org/pack/configuration/MyConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver]: Factory method 'loadTimeWeaver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-instrument-{version}.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.org.pack.app.Application.main(Application.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Comment: Are you deploying the application in an application server or trying to start it from the console or IDE? Please publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, not just incomplete POM snippets here. Make your problem reproducible. Otherwise, you might have to wait forever for a helpful answer. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex, I tried both starting in console and in IDE. Both ended up in same error. By the way, the code will be then packed as Docker container and serve live loads as AWS ECS service.    I ll work on an MCVE and provide, as the actual one is part of an enterprise code.

Comment: @kriegaex, jus to add , when running in console, i m trying to start as a jar.

Comment: @kriegaex, Pleae refer the sample code in [link] (https://github.com/ArvindAbi/aspectjltwdemo/tree/main/IssueREproduce) , Also attached the error in txt file when starting the jar with javaagents. I have been asepectj version of 1.9.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update 2024-03-19

If you are running your applications as **executable JARs on JRE 9+** (Spring Boot ones or other types), probably [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file) is what you want.

It enables you to embed a java agent in your executable JAR and have it started automatically using the [`Launcher-Agent-Class` JVM mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Unique features added by this plugin and unavailable via the original JVM mechanism: You can

- embed and run **multiple agents** (the JVM supports only one out of the box),
- pass an **option string** to each agent, just like from the JVM command line.

Spoiler: I am the author of the plugin and also happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ.

P.S.: In the case of the AspectJ weaver, as the JVM starts the agent very early, weaving will be active without extra Spring configuration and it should work for all classloaders - no more `ClassLoader [...] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method` errors as seen when hot-attaching the weaver via `spring-instrument.jar`.

#### Updated answer after MCVE was provided

##### Faulty aspect

Firstly, your aspect was faulty, it would never have matched anything. The pointcut

```
set(@com.example.TestAspect * *)
```

was faulty, because `TestAspect` is not an annotation. The correct
pointcut is

```
set(@com.example.TestAnnotation * *)
```

##### Faulty Java command line

You used (single line, line breaks added for readability)

```
java
  -jar target/aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  -javagent:/Users/carvind/IssueREproduce/javaagents/spring-instrument.jar
  -javaagent:/Users/carvind/IssueREproduce/javaagents/aspectjweaver.jar
```

There is a typo `-javagent` instead of `javaagent` in the first agent parameter. But the bigger problem is the argument order. Everything after `-jar my.jar` will be treated as program arguments for the main class. I.e., the `-javaagent` JVM arguments need to come **before** `-jar`.

You actually do not need both agents either. Your application works with

- either `spring-instument` + `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`
- or `aspectjweaver` **without** `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`.

If you accept my [pull request](https://github.com/ArvindAbi/aspectjltwdemo/pull/1), pull and then rebuild all your modules, you can successfully run the application from the root directory as follows:

```
$ java -javaagent:IssueREproduce/javaagents/spring-instrument.jar -jar IssueREproduce/aspectjlib/target/aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _   
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \  
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ 
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / 
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2024-01-09 10:03:56.975  INFO 20472 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : Starting AspectjlibApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Xander-UB with PID 20472 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616\IssueREproduce\aspectjlib\target\aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar start
ed by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616)
2024-01-09 10:03:56.983  INFO 20472 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.19 built on Wednesday Dec 21, 2022 at 06:57:22 PST
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] info register classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a                                                                                                         
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] info using configuration file:/C:/Users/alexa/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616/IssueREproduce/aspectjlib/target/aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/META-INF/aop.xml
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] info register aspect com.example.TestAspect
2024-01-09 10:03:58.330  INFO 20472 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : Started AspectjlibApplication in 2.297 seconds (JVM running for 3.071)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.String com.example.TestModel1.field1)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel1' (TestModel1.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.Double com.example.TestModel1.field4)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel1' (TestModel1.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
set(String com.example.TestModel1.field1)
set(Double com.example.TestModel1.field4)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.Integer com.example.TestModel2.field2)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel2' (TestModel2.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@1bce4f0a] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(boolean com.example.TestModel2.field3)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel2' (TestModel2.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
set(Integer com.example.TestModel2.field2)
set(boolean com.example.TestModel2.field3)
```

Or after removing `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` and another rebuild:

```
$ java -javaagent:IssueREproduce/javaagents/aspectjweaver.jar -jar IssueREproduce/aspectjlib/target/aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.19 built on Wednesday Dec 21, 2022 at 06:57:22 PST
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] info register classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] info using configuration file:/C:/Users/alexa/Documents/java-src/SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616/IssueREproduce/aspectjlib/target/aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/META-INF/aop.xml
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] info register aspect com.example.TestAspect

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2024-01-09 10:05:36.669  INFO 9836 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : Starting AspectjlibApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Xander-UB with PID 9836 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616\IssueREproduce\aspectjlib\target\aspectjlib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started
 by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_SprintBootError_77763616)
2024-01-09 10:05:36.674  INFO 9836 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2024-01-09 10:05:37.699  INFO 9836 --- [           main] c.e.aspectjlib.AspectjlibApplication     : Started AspectjlibApplication in 1.712 seconds (JVM running for 2.836)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.String com.example.TestModel1.field1)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel1' (TestModel1.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.Double com.example.TestModel1.field4)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel1' (TestModel1.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
set(String com.example.TestModel1.field1)
set(Double com.example.TestModel1.field4)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(java.lang.Integer com.example.TestModel2.field2)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel2' (TestModel2.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
[LaunchedURLClassLoader@7113b13f] weaveinfo Join point 'field-set(boolean com.example.TestModel2.field3)' in Type 'com.example.TestModel2' (TestModel2.java:7) advised by before advice from 'com.example.TestAspect' (TestAspect.java)
set(Integer com.example.TestModel2.field2)
set(boolean com.example.TestModel2.field3)
```

If you compare the log output, you see that `aspectjweaver` kicks in earlier than `spring-instrument`, which makes it more powerful and universal, if your aspects also weave Spring classes. It depends on the use case, if `spring-instrument` is enough or not. Here, both work fine.

#### Original answer

Simply use JVM parameter `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.9.x.jar`. When starting Spring or Spring Boot apps from the console, I never managed to get them working without a Java agent on the command line. Your custom weaver bean does not work with all classloaders, as you can see from the error message.

According to the hint in all [release notes](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/release/README-1.9.21.adoc#use-ltw-on-java-16) from AspectJ releases since 1.9.8 or so, you also need `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` on the JVM command line on JDK 16+. Sorry, but this is not AspectJ's fault. More recent JDKs simply do not provide a proper replacement for the now restricted APIs the load-time weaver needs to do its job.

Comment: Attached the MCVE , as a reply to your above comment.  I m passing the aspectjweaver 1.9.19 version , spring-instrument.jar , but the error remains the same,  By the way, i m using open jdk  11.0.15

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. Without it, it would have been next to impossible to find out what was wrong. Now, I can answer your question, see my update. You made two basic mistakes, one in the aspect and one regarding the JVM command line. Please keep up the good practice of always providing an MCVE right when asking the question. Do not make the volunteers trying to help you beg for a reproducer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S.: If you want to stick with Java 11, you can upgrade to Spring Boot 2.7.18. For Spring 3, you would need Java 17.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Problems fixed.   I kept my aop.xml to include only the Aspect i created . As I want to use aspectJ only for that aspect and rest of the aspects needs to be taken care by Spring AOP.

Comment: What do you mean, you kept aop.xml? I didn't remove it.

Comment: My sincere apologies, It is not.  In the PR it seemed like it was removed.  Not used to Github diff much.

Comment: I only removed the copy in the _target/classes_ directory, not the one in _src/main/resources_. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69xLD.png) from the PR, or simply check for yourself. Sorry, with all due respect: The problem sits in front of the computer. 